# Python iterating through folders and \ characters

Tags: python

I have an old project I wanted to post up on gh-pages and I have a bunch of html files in a bunch of folders.

So I've been piecing together a piece of python that would create an index page displaying all the contained html hyperlinks so that the content will be browse-able on gh-pages similarly to how it is done with full on web servers such as Apache.

To get started I have all the content printing in one file but unfortunately python is throwing file locations as py r'Strings' where `\` is escaped with a `\`.
I have been trying to prevent this from causing IO errors but have been getting a little stuck.

```
import os

class indexer:
    path = "~"
    prod = []
    def __init__(self,p):
        self.path=p
    def HtmlFrek(self,k):
        print("rek")
        os.chdir(k)
        ret="<h1>"+k+"</h1>"
        files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.split(".")[len(f.split("."))-1]=="html"]
        for t in files:
            t.replace(".","")
            t.replace("\\","/")
            ret+= "<a href = http://krewn.github.io/datasci"+k+">"+k+"</a>\n"
        folders = [x[0] for x in os.walk('.')]
        for k in folders:
            print k
            if(k == '.'):
                continue
            print k
            ret+="<div class='blue1'>"
            ret+=self.HtmlFrek(k)
            ret = "</div>"
        os.chdir("..")
        return(ret)

    def HtmlProd(self):
        print("start")
        ret = []
        ret.append("""<!DOCTYPE html><html>""")
        ret.append("<div class = 'ClearShadeLeft'>")
        folders = [x[0] for x in os.walk('.')]
        for k in folders:
            ret[1]+="<div class='blue1'>"
            ret[1]+=self.HtmlFrek(k)
            ret[1] = "</div>"

        ret[1] = "</div>"
        ret.append("""<\html><html>""")
        self.prod = ret
        return(ret)

i = indexer(".")
i.HtmlProd()
print i.prod
for k in i.prod:
    print k
print()
```

Edit: I think the answer here is to replace os.walk with `[f for f in os.listdir(somedir) if os.path.isfile(f)]`.

Another Edit:

This version of the code works...

```
import os

class indexer:
    path = "~"
    site = "http://krewn.github.io"
    proj = "Reprogramming"
    prod = []
    loc=[]

    def __init__(self,p):
        self.path=p
    def fprep(self,name):
        name.replace(".","")
        name.replace("\\","/")
        return(name)
    def refPrep(self):
        ref = self.site+"/"+self.proj
        for qw in self.loc:
            ref+="/"+qw
        return(ref)
    def HtmlFrek(self,adir):
        self.loc.append(adir)
        os.chdir(adir)
        ret="<h2>"+adir+"</h2>"
        files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.split(".")[len(f.split("."))-1]=="html"]
        for t in files:
            ret+="<a href ="+self.refPrep()+"/"+self.fprep(t)+">"+self.fprep(t)+"</a><br>\n"
        images = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.split(".")[len(f.split("."))-1]=="png"]
        for i in images:
            i = self.fprep(i)
            ref = self.refPrep()
            ret+= "<img src="+ref+"/"+i+">\n"
        folders = [f for f in os.listdir(".") if not os.path.isfile(f)]
        for k in folders:
            if(k.__contains__(".")):
                continue
            ret+="<div class='blue1'>"
            ret+=self.HtmlFrek(k)
            ret+="</div>"
        os.chdir("..")
        del self.loc[len(self.loc)-1]
        return(ret)

    def HtmlProd(self):
        print("start")
        ret = ""
        ret+="""<!DOCTYPE html><html>"""
        ret+="<div>"
        files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.split(".")[len(f.split("."))-1]=="html"]
        for t in files:
            ret+="<a href ="+self.refPrep()+"/"+self.fprep(t)+">"+self.fprep(t)+"</a><br>\n"
        folders = [f for f in os.listdir(".") if not os.path.isfile(f)]
        for k in folders:
            if(k.__contains__(".")):
                continue
            print k
            ret+="<div>"
            ret+=self.HtmlFrek(k)
            ret+="</div>"
        ret+="</div>"
        ret+="""</html>"""
        self.prod = ret
        return(ret)

i = indexer(".")
q=i.HtmlProd()
#print i.prod

w = open("index.html","w")
w.write(q)
w.close()
```

Comment: Could you post a smaller example with just the code that doesn't work? If you could make it print to the console and show the incorrect printout that would also help us see what's wrong and better answer your question.

Comment: Guarantee you will be able to simplify your code if you use Python's built in os.walk method (see https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk).

Comment: @Emil, sry it's a recursive function with a initial call and a main recursive method. I wrapped it in a class but nixing that would only save 2 lines or so.

Comment: @djmoch, I used os.walk, apparently in the wrong way...

Answer (score 0):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) is your friend for this sort of thing. You give doxygen a source code folder. You specify what file extensions that you consider to be source. Then it goes off and builds an index of everything in the folder. You can output this in html or as a pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I worked it out though. I find it really satisfying to get my hands dirty and explore how much control and potential I can build into my code.